# Recall a NSOperation with NSURLConnection if it fails

Tags: objective-c, nsurlconnection, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I have a `NSURLConnection` in `NSOperation`. This `NSOperation` is in `NSOperationQueue`. So, I wanted to know, how to recall the `NSOperation` if `NSURLConnection` has failed with clean code.
(I want to say that in the case `NSURLConnection` fails during the download for example)

Answer (score 1):

There's an existing open source library that will do a lot of this for you. It's [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking).

What's more, the class that you'll often use, `AFURLConnectionOperation` is itself a subclass of `NSOperation`.

You use blocks to set the code that `AFURLConnectionOperation` will execute:

```
- (void)setUploadProgressBlock:(void (^)(NSUInteger bytesWritten, long long totalBytesWritten, long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite))block;
- (void)setDownloadProgressBlock:(void (^)(NSUInteger bytesRead, long long totalBytesRead, long long totalBytesExpectedToRead))block;
- (void)setAuthenticationAgainstProtectionSpaceBlock:(BOOL (^)(NSURLConnection *connection, NSURLProtectionSpace *protectionSpace))block;
- (void)setAuthenticationChallengeBlock:(void (^)(NSURLConnection *connection, NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *challenge))block;
- (void)setRedirectResponseBlock:(NSURLRequest * (^)(NSURLConnection *connection, NSURLRequest *request, NSURLResponse *redirectResponse))block;
- (void)setCacheResponseBlock:(NSCachedURLResponse * (^)(NSURLConnection *connection, NSCachedURLResponse *cachedResponse))block;
```

Just add the `AFURLConnectionOperation` to your `NSOperationQueue` as normal.

`AFHTTPRequestOperation` is very useful also. It's created with an `AFHTTPClient` and `NSMutableURLRequest`:

```
AFHTTPClient *client = [AFHTTPClient clientWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [client requestWithMethod:@"GET" path:nil parameters:nil];
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc]initWithRequest:request];
```

Success or failure is easy and again, it's handle with the new trendy blocks rather than old school delegate callbacks:

```
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation * request, id response)
 {
        // ... my success block
 }
 failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *request, NSError *error)
 {
    // ... my failure block
 }];
```